# how to fix Array index out of bounds exception

Tags: java

Hi i am learning java for past few days only when i try to execute a simple program i got an ArrayIndexoutofbounds exception during run time pls help me to fix this exception

here is my code

```
  class Armstrong 
    {
      public static void main(String args[])
       {
         if (args.length!=0) {
            System.out.println("value is required");
            System.exit(0);
           }
         int num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
         int n = num;
         int check =0, remainder;
         while(num>0)
          {
            remainder = num%10;
            check = check+(int)Math.pow(remainder,3);
            num = num/10;
          }
         if (check==n)
           System.out.println(n+ "isa armstrong number");
         else 
           System.out.println(n + "is not a armstrong number");
         }
       }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: As ashutosh mentioned look at the question and also look at the document to understand how and why it occurs. The args length should be checked for zero, if you want to throw error. You are throwing an error currently if the args length is not equal to zero.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a value then `if (args.length!=0) {` should be

```
if (args.length==0) {
```

because you terminate when the condition is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Change condition from

```
 if (args.length!=0)
```

to

```
 if (args.length<=0)
```

As it throw if args has no any value than it throw this error.